# ng-model object to string

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-directive

I have to select tags in my HTML:

```
<select ng-model="myUnit" ng-options="unit.thisunit for unit in units"></select>
<select ng-model="myUnit2" ng-options="unit2.thisunit2 for unit2 in units2 </select>
```

And I have a button where I want to pass the VALUE of the hg-model.

```
<button class="button button-block button-balanced" ng-click="convert(myUnit, myUnit2)">
    Convert
</button>
```

Here is my function:

```
$scope.convert = function(myUnit, myUnit2){
    alert(myUnit);
}
```

The issue is that myUnit prints out: [object Object]

I want the actual value of the object... e.g "Kilometer"

How do I accomplish this?

Comment: We can't know because we don't know the structure of the object. You should expect the unit in the console. Use console.log instead of alert and have a look at it. That'll tell you which bit you need ot be looking at.

Comment: Ah duh... I just figured it out by your response.

Comment: Tell us what the object looks like then. For those that come after.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can `Stringify` any valid JS Object aka Java Script Object Notation.

Use: `JSON.stringify(myUnit)`